# Discord.py не может запуститься при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, discord, discord.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio
import time

URL = 'https://stopgame.ru/news'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0', 'accept':'*/*'}
link = 'https://stopgame.ru'
Token = ''
api_key = "I need your token"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"

PREFIX = 'lu.'
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')


def get_html(url, params=None):
    while True:
        r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = params )
        return r
        time.sleep(10)

v = []
newsw = []
bb = []

def get_content(html):


    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for x in soup.select('.article-summary .caption'):
        newsw.append(x.get_text(strip=True))
    
    articles = soup.find_all('div', class_='caption caption-bold')
    for a in articles:
        bb.append(link+a.find('a')['href'])

    yu = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'info-item timestamp')
    for c in yu:
        v.append(c.get_text())
  
    return v, newsw, bb
def parse():
    while  True:
        html = get_html(URL)
        print (html)
        get_content (html.text)

        time.sleep(10)
parse()


@client.command()
async def stopgame(ctx):
    cvh = discord.Embed(title = 'StopGame', color = 0xFF0000)
    cvh.add_field(name = 'Заголовок:', value = f'1. {newsw[0]} \n 2. {newsw[1]} \n 3. {newsw[2]} \n 4. {newsw[3]} \n 5. {newsw[4]}')
    cvh.add_field(name = 'Ссылка:', value = f'1.{bb[0]} \n 2.{bb[1]} \n 3.{bb[2]} \n 4.{bb[3]} \n 5.{bb[4]}')
    cvh.add_field(name = 'Дата:', value = f'1. {v[0]} \n 2. {v[1]} \n 3. {v[2]} \n 4. {v[3]} \n 5. {v[4]}')
    cvh.set_footer(text=f'Нет, код не списан у Хавуди Хо (Я серъезно)', icon_url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/776796284152971274/793456242201853982/unnamed.jpg')
    await ctx.send(embed = cvh)
client.run(Token)
```

Discord.py не может запуститься, когда выполняются следующие строчки кода:

```
def parse():
    while  True:
        html = get_html(URL)
        print (html)
        get_content (html.text)

        time.sleep(10)
parse()
```

Без while код выполняется, но я хочу сделать так, чтобы он парсил новую информацию каждые 10 секунд.
Результат c while:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат без while:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас не предусмотрен выход  или завершение def parse()

Comment: не предусмотрен.

Comment: можете расписать логику работы (прежде всего, для себя): из чего состоит, кто что вызывает, что отправляется в ответ и т.д.?

Comment: Что значит *Код не может запуститься из-за функции parse*? Ну, уберите эту функцию, раз из-за неё не запускается.

Comment: Тут моя ошибка. Я поменял текст вопроса.

Comment: Запускайте в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.py` - асинхронная библиотека. `requests` - синхронная.

`requests` и `time.sleep` [блокируют](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code) выполнение основного цикла.

В основном, всё что выполняется более 100ms - считается блокирующим.

1. Используйте асинхронную библиотеку для веб-запросов, например [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/).
2. Для "сна" используйте `asyncio.sleep` вместо `time.sleep`.
3. Используйте [`asyncio tasks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) для выполнения функции "в фоне".

   - `discord.py` имеет встроенное расширения для упрощённого управления задачами в контексте дискорд-ботов: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

В итоге ваша блокирующая функция должна выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```py
import aiohttp
from discord.ext import tasks

...

async def get_html(url, params=None):
    # raise_for_status - поднимаем исключение если статус ответа >=400
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params) as response:
            return response

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def parse():
    try:
        html = await get_html(URL)
    except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        get_content(html.text)

parse.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю циклы вообще не нужны, есть же сущность бота, а у нее события, вот ближайший код который я делал для пересылки сообщений в телеграм (JS для питона долно быть точно такое же решение, но с питоновским синтаксисом):

```
discordClient.on('message', msg => {
  if (DISCORD_CONFIG.channels.indexOf(msg.channel.name) >= 0) {
    functions.resendMessage(msg);
  }
});
```

Вот для питона:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      await message.channel.send('C Новым Годом! ')
```

[How to Make a Discord Bot in Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1226245/edit)

Что касается discord.ext (вот пример из документации):

```
async def on_ready(): pass
async def my_message(message): pass

bot.add_listener(on_ready)
bot.add_listener(my_message, 'on_message')
```

[discord.ext API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html)

В общем и целом боты пишутся примерно одинаково на любом языке.